# loading the properties file

Tags: java, properties

I wanted to read some properties file. 
For that I created a small program which reads, writes and also updates this properties file.

Now some people are saying the properties file should be read only once, that means when the class is loaded it should read once, not multiple times for each key.

So I have to read the properties file inside a static block.

Now my doubt if I make any new entry to the properties file, will it be loaded the new entry ?

Please suggest me which is the correct way to design the loading of properties file.

```
public class Parser {

    private String path;

    private static Properties prop = new Properties();

    public Parser(String path) throws IOException{

        this.path = path;

        load();

    }

    public  Model readPropertiesFile(){

        Model model = new Model();

        model.setName(prop.getProperty("name"));

        return model ;



    }

    public void createOrUpdatePropertiesFile(Model model){

        prop.setProperty("name", model.getName());
    }

    public void setPath(String path){
         this.path = path;
    }

    public String getPath(){
        return path ;
    }



    public  void load() throws IOException{

        File file = new File(path);
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
              System.out.println("File created..");
        }
                        prop.load(new FileInputStream(file));





    }
```

Comment: property file should be loaded in run time(dynamically).can you show your code what your tried?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (as opposed to code snippets or 400 lines).

Comment: properties file is typically used to read the configuration details for the application and ideally it should remain read-only. If your app requires frequent writes use db for that. If you change the properties file you should restart the application. Also beware that when you override the properties you would loose the comments in that file.

Comment: Thats ok. But can you suggest me the design of the code? How to read? should it be in the static block ?

Comment: You can read it in static block so that the properties are loaded at class loading time

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ways;

- Load properties file from classpath

  ```
  public static Properties load(String propsName) throws Exception {
       Properties props = new Properties();
       URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(propsName);
       props.load(url.openStream());
       return props;
  }
  ```
- Load a properties file

  ```
   public static Properties load(File propsFile) throws IOException {
       Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(propsFile);
        props.load(fis);    
        fis.close();
        return props;
   }
  ```